# Comment traduissez vous cette phrase

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I am reading about French history

" A cote d'eux apparaissent des personnages moins prestigieux, mais dont le point de vue eclaire l'historie: un habitant de Jerusalem relatant les horreurs de la prise de la ville par les croises, un poete africain decrivant sans complaisance l'arrivee des colons europeens, une danseuse americaine creant un reseau de resistance.

Mais au-dela de la presentation de ces evenements et de ces personnages, des pages thematiques s'attachent a montrer la lente maturation des idees qui font evoluer la societe francaise. : debuts du christianisme, progres des sciences et des techniques grandes decouvertes, transformations sociales du 19e siecle, evolution des arts et de la litterature, appartition du chomage et de la fracture sociale, etc.

Enfin, des < (comme celles consacrees a la vie des chasseurs de rennes ou a la construction des cathedrales) permettent d'immerger totalement le lecture dans un passe que la precision et la poesie de l'illustration renden particulierement vivant"

My translation

Side of them appears as not so prestigious people, but who aspect of life enlight the history: habitants of Jerusalem related to the horror of the priest and the Crusaders, a poet of Afrquie describes without compliance the arrival of the colonies in Europe, a dancer of America creating a network of resistance.

But below presentation on those events and those people, is a page of temathics attached and showing the slow mutation of the idea of evolution of the French revolution. The start of Christianity , the progress of science and techniques, the great discoveries , transformming the society of 20e century. evolution of arts and literature, appearance of the unemployment and social divisions.

At the end, < page of dreamm> the one dedicated the life of hunters of deers and construction of catherdrals. allowing the immersion of total lecture in the past who precisely the poesy specifically describes lively.

Can you please confirm my translation thanks.

Comment: Google translate (although not perfect) gives a considerably better translation than yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation is FUBAR. Would you like a proper one, or simply for every mistake you made to be pointed out, explained to you and corrected? What I mean is: do you need a decent translation, or was it a simple self-test to hone your skills in French?

A cote d'eux apparaissent des personnages moins prestigieux, mais dont le point de vue eclaire l'historie: un habitant de Jerusalem relatant les horreurs de la prise de la ville par les croises, un poete africain decrivant sans complaisance l'arrivee des colons europeens, une danseuse americaine creant un reseau de resistance.

Among them, other, lesser-known figures whose viewpoints ans feelings shed a new light on/rekindle official History: a citizen of Jerusalem telling of the horrors he witnessed when Crusaders raided the city, a griot describing warts-and-all the arrival of European settlers, an American dancer (Josephine Baker) leading a French resistance network during WW2.

Mais au-dela de la presentation de ces evenements et de ces personnages, des pages thematiques s'attachent a montrer la lente maturation des idees qui font evoluer la societe francaise. : debuts du christianisme, progres des sciences et des techniques grandes decouvertes, transformations sociales du 19e siecle, evolution des arts et de la litterature, appartition du chomage et de la fracture sociale, etc.

Beyond this gallery of anecdotal characters and events, thematic sections throughout the book are dedicated to the accurate depiction of the slow changes French society and mentality undertook in History: the beginnings of Christianity, scientific and technical progress, great discoveries, new forms of art and litterature, increase in the unemployment rate and subsequent social dislocation, etc.

Comment: I know some staff is not well aligned so logic is not good, but other parts I think should be fine

Comment: They are not. Off by a long shot. Offer still stands.

Comment: if nothing is good enough all translation should be cool if possible